# Compute the percentage of summed grouped values in long format

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a table:

```
        Date       SYMBOL ID
1       2019-03-12      A  1
2       2019-03-19      A  2
3       2019-03-20      A  1
4       2019-03-21      A  2
5       2019-03-22      A  1
6       2019-03-23      A  2
```

The goal is the append a column to each row which calculates the percentage of the ID value as sum of all IDs grouped by symbol.

```
SUM(IDs) grouped by Symbol / ID
```

Currently I do this by first calculating the sum

```
percentBase <- aggregate(ID~SYMBOL, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

And afterwards using apply to calculate the percentage

```
computePercentage <- function(row,output){
  as.integer(row[3]) / percentBase[percentBase$SYMBOL==row[2],2]
}

df$percentage <- apply(df,1,computePercentage)
```

Using apply and constantly casting takes a long time and is inefficient. How to properly solve this task?

Comment: `with(df, ID/ave(ID, SYMBOL, FUN = sum))` or with `dplyr` , `df %>%
  group_by(SYMBOL) %>%
  mutate(percentage = ID/sum(ID))`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks. do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks. But this has been asked before so I closed it as duplicate of the original post. :)